# How to ensure a value being inserted into a table exists in another table?

Tags: mysql

I'm probably either missing something or hopefully just overthinking this but...

The scenario is that I have a MySQL database with several tables, most of them have primary and foreign keys in place and are working as expected.

But for this particular table, I wish it to only accept values for a particular field if that value exists in a field in another table.

So an example, I have the following;

```
Faults

ID     fault
1      electrical
2      mechanical
3      electrical
4      operational
5      electrical


Log

ID     date     fault
1      300420   mechanical
2      010520   other
3      030520   mechanical
4      040520   electrical
```

(there are many duplicates in **Faults.fault** for other reasons and this can not be avoided in this instance.)

Now I only want to be able to add rows to Log if the **Log.fault** value exists in **Faults.fault**.

So, with the below;

```
INSERT INTO Log (date, fault)
VALUE ('040520','hydraulic');
```

How can I ensure that this only allows **'hydraulic'** to be added if it exists in **Faults.fault** which it currently does not?

I initially thought about creating composite keys and also tried looking into conditional inserts but really not getting anywhere, especially with the latter.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Looks like you need a table which contains distinct faults

Comment: Where did 'if it exists in Area.fault' come from you previously stated you had 2 tables faults and log – and you are 'INSERT INTO Fault ' - a table which does not exist and if supposed to be faults does not contain a date. Please review your question and make it consistent. and while doing that remove the waffle.